# the app is not seen in itunes connect after successfull uploading from xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I uploaded the app from xcode, and it uploaded successfully. Then i discovered that this version appeared in "activity" and it was in processing state. Then in a minute it just dissapears everytime. I dont know what to do. I don't know if apple sent me an email or not.
Because the currently used developer email is not longer working.

So i don't know if i can change the email of the developer without any damage to the app(certificates,permissions and etc.).  Can you suggest what to do in this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because some iOS 10 requirements for info file missed. Try to debug app on REAL device with iOS 10 and look for debug messages when app crashes. Check for "Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description" in info file and other keys beginning from Privacy

Comment: i know. but it didn't help. I've added the missed privacy keys to info.plist. And also added localization. But it doesnt work. The only thing im using is photos. I dont use camera or location. So actually i don't know what to do

Comment: What about "Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"?

Comment: LUL. thats strange. Im not using camera. But i added camera privacy and it worked. wtf apple

Comment: @nerowolfe same issue with me i add all key but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of missed keys in the info.plist. 
For example if you are using camera then you need to include it info.plist.

[image]

If you included key without any value then apple will discard that build.
Please check your mail, you could have received the warning mail for the same.

[image]

Comment: LUL. thats strange. Im not using camera. But i added camera privacy and it worked. wtf apple

Comment: @JenyaKirmiza : I have used camera for reference.

Comment: i wrote in the description "Actually i dont use camera" ))