# uploaded app from xcode 8 and Application Loader but build not visible in itunes connect

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, ios10, xcode8

I have uploaded app from Xcode 8 and Application Loader also and build showing processing but after few min that build is not visible on iTunes connect.

[image]

### After uploaded application build

[image]

### After 5 to 10 min refreshing screen build not visible

[image]

Comment: does your current build contain still Processing tag in "All Builds" section? i.e. 1.2 (Processing)

Comment: No, After refreshing screen that 1.2 build not visible on iTunes connect. We submitted 3 builds but same problem happen with build

Comment: Have you checked your mail, you could have received the warning mail for it.

Comment: we have not received any warning mail.

Comment: Please check whether this is helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993213/the-app-is-not-seen-in-itunes-connect-after-successfull-uploading-from-xcode/39993756#39993756

Comment: Can you please provide info on what user access you want in your app?

Comment: So your problem is that it's still processing after 10 mins?

Comment: check for email from apple for any processing errors

Comment: we have not received any processing error mail from apple and still it not showing build in iTunes connect.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Xcode 8.0 and later please create a .pch file
and add the following

```
#ifndef __IPHONE_8_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 8.0 and later."
#endif
```

Then build to iTunes connect. This worked for me

Comment: also import the #import <Availability.h>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Delete browser history and login again to itunessconncet.
2. Wait few minutes more.

Answer (score -3):

Your header version 1.0 but your build 1.2 is a problem that may be ?

Comment: Its build number not app version. App Version 1.0 and build is 1.2

Comment: You may be right, but it used to don't work for iTunes is a difference between these two numbers. 
Maybe if you try to solve

Comment: I just remembered sent me this e-mail :

*This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

*This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: we already updated privacy setting.. still we are facing same issue